# Get all the running instances using nagios

Tags: plugins, nagios

I have a certain number of hosts running different servers. All of them have nagios plugin installed. I wanted to write a script that would tell me daily if all the instances are up and running.
I tried opsview, but due to certain restrictions, I couldn't go ahead with it. It was then that I decided to use the nagios plugin directly. I thought about NRPE but it would be used to run a plugin remotely (provided you must know the address of the host), but in my case, I want to know if someone added a new server overnight, or some server failed or what all servers are running.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios doesn't do discovery.  You configure it with a list of machines and services to check.

Assuming we're talking about cloud servers, AWS can send you a message when a new server is added.  See [the doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/ASGettingNotifications.html)  The message can be SNS or SQS.  These notifications could be read to rebuild your nagios configuration to match the auto-scale group.